# find set of words in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

In the example I made up below, I am trying to get the words `STEM Employment` from the `text` list. If I find those set of words in order, I would like to find the index number of the first word so I can then use that same index number for the `width` and `height` lists since they are parallel (meaning their len is always the same dynamic value)

```
teststring = ("STEM Employment").split(" ")

data = {"text":["some","more","STEM","Employment","data"],
        "width":[100,45,50,90,354],
        "height":[500,320,320,432,554]}
```

so for this example, the answer would be `50` and `320` because the first word is `STEM`. However I am not just looking for `STEM` I have to make sure that `Employment` follows right after `STEM` in the list.

I tried writing a forloop for this but my forloop stops short when it confirms the first word `STEM`. I am not sure how to fix it:

```
testchecker = 0
for testword in range(len(data)):
    print(data["text"][testword])
    for m in teststring:
        # print(m)
        print(testchecker)
        if m in data["text"][testword]:
            print("true")
            testchecker = testchecker + 1
            if testchecker == len(teststring):
                print("match")
                print(testword-testchecker+1)
            pass
        else:
            testchecker = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `data["text"]` a string with `join` and check for "STEM Employment" in that. Then find the index of "STEM".

```
teststring = "STEM Employment"
data = {"text":["some","more","STEM","Employment","data"],
        "width":[100,45,50,90,354],
        "height":[500,320,320,432,554]}
if teststring in " ".join(data["text"]):
    idx = data["text"].index(teststring.split(' ')[0])
    print(data["width"][idx], data["height"][idx])
```

Output:

```
50 320
```

Another option:

```
teststring = "STEM Employment".split(' ')
# Make sure all words in testring are in data["text"]
if all(s in data["text"] for s in teststring):
    # Get the indexes of each word
    indexes = [data["text"].index(s) for s in teststring]
    # Make sure all indexes are sequential
    if all(b - a == 1 for a, b in zip(indexes, indexes[1:])):
        print(data["width"][indexes[0]], data["height"][indexes[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp! I tested the code in numerous was and it works! When I thought about how you did that, (The `join` method) it was very ingenious. Kinda blew my mind as I was reading through the code how easy you made it. lol Thanks again

Comment: Actually, after testing this some more, it seems this doesn't work actually. I will still give you credit but I will have to figure out the rest. Essentially, this doesn't work if there are multiple words that are similar in value. That is because `idx = data["text"].index(teststring.split(' ')[0])` only grabs the FIRST word's index; NOT the first phase's index. That is my fault because I didn't structure the question correctly so this is technically correct. I should have used the word `phrase` rather than word.